# How do Google Docs bubble cards / link preview / unfurl external resource inside google document?

Tags: javascript, metadata, google-docs, google-docs-api, prefetch

Good day,

**Preface**

a while ago google has introduced a nifty feature of loading a rich-text preview of a site, when a link is recognized and clicked upon. It's also called unfurling.

**Examples:**

- [Example with a sofa preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVEWH.png)
- [This image shows how yahoo sumbits randomized news articles to the bubble box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMnCb.png)

**What's my goal?**

I wanted to use this feature to integrate a web-based image library with google docs, to enable creative movie script writing, where links to items in the library get a proper preview.

**Attempted solutions:**

- Adding meta tags
- Adding og tags
- Adding twitter tags
- Adding an oEmbed response

**Problem:**

And yet, while twitter, slack and other platforms started recognizing the previews, google seems to be using their own undocumented protocol, fueled apparently by JS scripts loaded with the google document.

As I've said, I was able to find any documentation, and the search lead me to a question [On what basis, the link preview is showing a card with title and image of a website link?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/22081226?hl=en) which figuratively says to buzz off with the tread closed and no useful information given.

While https://yahoo.com manages to send the news with images and text, https://stackoverflow.com/ itself knows how to work with the API and sends useful text information to the google doc.

- [Stackoverflow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYJSi.png) *(favicon, title and url are being submitted)*

So I ask you, to shed some light, if you're able to, on this awesome feature :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My research suggests the only way to make links unfurl is for Google Search to have discovered them. In other words, links have to be public and spidered, and therefore in Google search indices. Unfurling never causes direct inbound network requests. That's as much as I can tell.

Also, I directly tested and proved above hypothesis with some URLs on our own site.

But, I could be wrong. As you say, there is zero official documentation on this topic.